# Fourier Transform of $\exp\left[-e^{-k^2}\right]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, fourier-transform

I want to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of $\exp\left[-e^{-k^2}\right]$. One of the ways I can imagine is to expand the exponential in a series
$$
\exp\left[-e^{-k^2}\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{-nk^2}
$$

The first of the series gives a inverse Fourier Transform of $\delta(x)$, the rest is a sum over Gaussian. How can I evaluate this series to get a solution? Can I predict what will be the leading behaviour in the case of $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: The function $u(x) = \mathrm{epx}(e^{-x^2})$ is not integrable, but $v = u-1$ is integrable, and corresponds to remove the Dirac delta from the Fourier transform. Then the Fourier transform of $v$ converges to $C:= \widehat v(0) = \int_{\Bbb R} v$, and so in some sense $\widehat u(x) = \delta(x) + C + o(1)$ when $x\to 0$.